# Divs sendo adicionadas uma em cima da outra

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho três menus, quando eu clico em cada um, ele deixa uma div que estava como `display:none` como `display:block`. O que está acontecendo, é que seu clicar no Menu 1 e depois no Menu 2, ele está adicionando uma div em baixo da outra.

O Jquery está assim:

```
$( "#dadosTecnicos" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarDadosTecnicos" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
});

$( "#galeria" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarGaleria" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
});

$( "#downloads" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarDownload" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
});
```

Por exemplo: ao clicar no `id` **dadosTecnicos** ele mostra a div `mostrarDadosTecnicos` se depois eu clicar em `galeria`, o `mostrarGaleria`vai ficar em baixo de `mostrarDadosTecnicos`.

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/2NNe8/)

Comment: Sera que você poderia fazer no http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Claro. Está assim: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/2NNe8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que quando você exibe um você esquece de desaparecer os outros dois

no exemplo abaixo eu usei o `.hide()` de uma olhada [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/BD3KS/)

**Código**

```
$( "#dadosTecnicos" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarDadosTecnicos" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
    $( "#mostrarGaleria" ).hide();
    $( "#mostrarDownload" ).hide();
});

$( "#galeria" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarGaleria" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
    $( "#mostrarDownload" ).hide();
    $( "#mostrarDadosTecnicos" ).hide();
});

$( "#downloads" ).click(function() {
    $( "#mostrarDownload" ).fadeToggle( 'fast', function() {});
    $( "#mostrarGaleria" ).hide();
    $( "#mostrarDadosTecnicos" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: Silvio, muito obrigado cara. Funcionou 100% :P

Comment: @FelipeStoker valeu ;)

Comment: Se por acaso, eu quisesse adicionar um CSS, quando a pessoa clica em um menu em específico, ele aplica uma cor ('blue' por exemplo) e muda a cor dos outros.

Você me indicaria usar `.css` informando as regras, ou `.addClass` criando uma classe para isso?

Comment: CTRL + C | CTRL + V

Comment: @FelipeStoker Acredito que usando `.addClass` ficaria mais organizado mas eu mesmo uso o `.css` por ser bem mais pratico e também acaba economizando código, no caso do `.addClass` ele é usado mais para classes grandes por exemplo com 10 propriedades de css, no caso de uma ou até duas o melhor é usar o `.css`